# Error: duplicate entry '0' for key 'primary' mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Buenas noches

Actualice phpMyAdmin y al exportar la base de datos e importarla en otro servidor me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

> duplicate entry '0' for key 'primary' mysql

Se lo que significa y que lo ocasiona.

Pero mi pregunta es la siguiente:
En mi versión anterior de phpMyAdmin me exportaba las bases de datos y las importaba sin ningun problema. En mi versión anterior las tablas se exportaban en este formato:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accion` (
  `id_accion` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre_accion` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `id_modulo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `mostrar` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `accion_padre` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `posicion` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_accion`),
  KEY `id_modulo` (`id_modulo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1210 ;
```

En la versión nueva de phpMyAdmin me la exporta de esta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE `accion` (
  `id_accion` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nombre_accion` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `id_modulo` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `mostrar` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `accion_padre` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `posicion` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

--
-- Indices de la tabla `accion`
--
ALTER TABLE `accion`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_accion`),
  ADD KEY `id_modulo` (`id_modulo`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `accion`
--
ALTER TABLE `accion`
  MODIFY `id_accion` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1210;
```

Como puedo configurar phpMyAdmin para que me genere la exportación en el formato anterior?

Si la exporto en MySQL Administrator me funciona correctamente, pero quiero resolverlo con phpMyAdmin

Si manualmente corrijo la segunda exportación para que quede como la primera me funciona perfectamente

---

Luego de [la respuesta de @wchiquito](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35518), agrego:

Esta es una de las tablas:

```
    CREATE TABLE `historico_usuarios` (
      `idregistro` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `estacion` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `fechayhora` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `historico_usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idregistro`);
ALTER TABLE `historico_usuarios`
  MODIFY `idregistro` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1260;
```

Y este es un el primer `insert` que realizo al ingresar a la aplicación para guardar un registro del ingreso del usuario:

```
mysql_query("insert into historico_usuarios 
                                (estacion,fechayhora,usuario) 
                            values ('$pc','$fh','$login')");
```

Los campos los validé y no son nulos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu edición Juan, se lee mucho mejor

Answer (score 1):

El cambio de formato al momento de exportar la tabla, en principio, no debería ser la causa del error: `duplicate entry '0' for key 'primary' mysql`.

Básicamente las tres (3) sentencias de la nueva versión de phpMyAdmin genera una definición de tabla igual que la versión instalada antes de actualizar.

¿Es posible mostrar las sentencias INSERT's causantes del error?.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Como puede observar en el ejemplo, no puedo reproducir el problema:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `historico_usuarios`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `historico_usuarios` (
    ->   `idregistro` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `estacion` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `fechayhora` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    ->   `usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `historico_usuarios`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: historico_usuarios
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `historico_usuarios` (
  `idregistro` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `estacion` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fechayhora` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE `historico_usuarios`
    ->   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idregistro`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE `historico_usuarios`
    ->   MODIFY `idregistro` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1260;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `historico_usuarios`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: historico_usuarios
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `historico_usuarios` (
  `idregistro` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `estacion` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fechayhora` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idregistro`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1260 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `historico_usuarios`
    ->   (`estacion`, `fechayhora`, `usuario`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('127.0.0.1', '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'user1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `idregistro`,
    ->   `estacion`,
    ->   `fechayhora`,
    ->   `usuario`
    -> FROM
    ->   `historico_usuarios`;
+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+
| idregistro | estacion  | fechayhora          | usuario |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+
|       1260 | 127.0.0.1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | user1   |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `historico_usuarios`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: historico_usuarios
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `historico_usuarios` (
  `idregistro` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `estacion` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fechayhora` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idregistro`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1261 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @damianlema: Por favor, vea la actualización de la respuesta.